# Login code crashes?

Tags: java, android, authentication

Currently, I have a login code, which will post data to a PHP script and read the data output by the script (JSON encoded) to determine if the login credentials are correct.

The following is part of my `LoginActivity.java`, called when the login button is clicked:

```
public void login(View view) {
    String usernameValue = username.getText().toString(),
            passwordValue = password.getText().toString(),
            orgValue = org.getText().toString();

    if (orgValue.matches("")) {
        snackbar.make(view, "Organisation cannot be blank", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (usernameValue.matches("")) {
        snackbar.make(view, "Username cannot be blank", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (passwordValue.matches("")) {
        snackbar.make(view, "Password cannot be blank", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        /**
         * Login code goes here.
         * This is where the error seems to be at.
         */

        URL url;
        String data;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://myurl.com/verify/users.php");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(usernameValue, "UTF-8") +
                    "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(passwordValue, "UTF-8") +
                    "&" + URLEncoder.encode("org", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(orgValue, "UTF-8");

            OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                int success = -1;
                String message = null;

                reader.beginArray();

                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    reader.beginObject();

                    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                        String name = reader.nextName();

                        switch (name) {
                            case "success":
                                success = reader.nextInt();
                                break;
                            case "error_message":
                                message = reader.nextString();
                                break;
                            default:
                                reader.skipValue();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    reader.endObject();
                }
                reader.endArray();
                reader.close();

                if (success == 1) {
                    snackbar.make(view, "You are successfully logged in as " + usernameValue + "!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    snackbar.make(view, "Error: " + message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                snackbar.make(view, "Error " + responseCode + " encountered. Please try again later.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I click the login button, the app crashed with the following message in the logcat:

```
04-24 16:55:24.251 16674-16674/com.example.android.loginexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.android.loginexample, PID: 16674
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5242)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10530)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21185)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5242) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10530) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21185) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                               Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
                                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:370)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:298)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:110)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:221)
                                                                                  at com.example.android.loginexample.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:68)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5242) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10530) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21185) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would not try to make a URL request in the main thread, and I suggest you to use [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask) for that.
However if you really want to do it in the main thread, you can write this in you activity's onCreate :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The above line tells it all. In android you cannot perform network operations in main thread. you are performing http request here. Instead of doing this use AsyncTask or different thread.